# Standard BIOS update caused BitLocker Recovery with no key

Tags: encryption, uefi, windows-11, lenovo-laptop, bitlocker

Lenovo Yoga 920-13ikb
bios 5NCN41WW
currently with Win11, likely upgraded from Win10 in the past
From approximately 2017-2018

“You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed.”

Helping someone with their Laptop, it was working fine no problems, I went to the Windows Update, and it had Optional update of UEFI/BIOS firmware, I did that, and it said to restart. After restart, Bitlocker went into recovery mode.

PC Owner never printed their Bitlocker Recovery Key. They have 2 Windows Users, I only went into 1 of the users, and it was a Local User, not a Microsoft Account User, so it appears that Bitlocker Recovery cannot be accessed from a MS Account. I never saw the other user, so it is possible that it is a MS Account with synced Bitlocker Recovery Key, so I asked the PC owner to log into their MS account from another device, but I followed directions from MS, and MS account explicitly said there was no Bitlocker synced device in their settings.

PC Owner likely never setup Bitlocker themselves, it likely came already activated with Lenovo’s OEM version of Windows. While Lenovo did not invent Microsoft’s Bitlocker, they provide you with an OEM version of Windows that has it already activated. I have viewed the temporary Boot Menu in the UEFI, there is no Lenovo OneKey Recovery option. I have seen many computers with Bitlocker device encryption already activated the first time you boot into windows. If this is so, where does Lenovo originally provide the recovery key? They must provide it to the purchaser somewhere!

It seems to me that in theory, if I perform a UEFI/BIOS version rollback, it will fit the Bitlocker checksum, or TPM key checksum or whatever it is called. Is that true, will that work?

I would also expect there is a button to push somewhere to revert the UEFI back a version. If this obvious feature is not provided by Lenovo, then my next question is if I manually perform a UEFI rollback, does that step destroy the TPM Key? If it destroys the TPM key, then it will not fix the Bitlocker issue. If I need to download the previous UEFI version from their website, then does anyone know why Lenovo only provides 1 UEFI version on their website, listed below? Shouldn’t they provide the older version as well?

I have seen multiple situations on other computers where if I make a change to the EFI partition for example, then bitlocker recovery mode happens, then if i revert the change, bitlocker recovery mode goes away. That is what I am suggesting with the UEFI rollback. I am well aware of the difference between the UEFI motherboard settings and the EFI partition on the disk, no low hanging fruit to grab there.

Lastly, of course no one will be shocked that the PC Owner has no backups of her files, and no cloud sync of her files.

I read an article that is very similar to this issue:

https://www.theregister.com/2022/08/15/bitlocker_microsoft/

On the Bitlocker recovery screen, to my surprise it actually says what caused this issue: “You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed.

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-920-13ikb/?linkTrack=Homepage%3ABody_Search%20Products&searchType=3&keyWordSearch=Yoga%20920-13IKB%20Laptop%20%28ideapad%29

Comment: Did the secure boot setting in the BIOS get changed from on to off during the update? If it was possible, did you make a backup of the BIOS settings before doing the update?

Answer (score 1):

> PC Owner likely never setup Bitlocker themselves, it likely came from Lenovo that way, if this is so, where does Lenovo originally provide the recovery key? They must provide it to the purchaser somewhere!

More likely it came from Windows installation this way. If the system configuration matches certain requirements, Windows may automatically try to enable the "Device Encryption" feature (which is like a feature-limited version of BitLocker that even Windows Home has).

As far as I know, this mode only sets up a recovery key when one logs in with a Microsoft account; if that was bypassed (e.g. if Lenovo pre-created a local account), then there might not *be* a recovery key at all.

Manufacturers which pre-install Windows generally don't bother ensuring a recovery key exists at all, much less printing it out.

> It seems to me that in theory, if I perform a UEFI/BIOS version rollback, it will fit the Bitlocker checksum, or TPM key checksum or whatever it is called.

Only if the TPM still contains the original "storage root key". Many devices that use an fTPM (i.e. a firmware-based TPM within the CPU rather than a discrete chip) tend to clear the TPM's state whenever firmware is downgraded (so that one couldn't deliberately downgrade to firmware with security issues), and sometimes even when it's upgraded.

(All data sealed by the TPM is encrypted using a master key that only the TPM itself has, so if it has been cleared and has generated a new master key, it can no longer understand the previously sealed data it's given – doesn't matter whether the PCR hash values are identical or not, if the TPM can't even get to the point where it could look at them.)

Aside from that, make sure that other system state is still in the same place: if Secure Boot was originally enabled, make sure it's still enabled.

Comment: Thank you for that intelligent and thoughtful response. I appreciate the detail, and your believing that this is what is happening.I have not changed the Secure Boot setting. This Bitlocker Recovery mode happened without me changing any settings in the UEFI.

Comment: User1686, have you heard of a Windows Update of the UEFI firmware causing this Bitlocker issue before? I have experienced the Bitlocker Recovery before, but never from a firmware update, that is new to me. I did also perform about 12 driver updates in Windows Update at the same time, and it was 100% finished downloading a Windows Cumulative update, which would be installed next, after restart, is there a small chance that it was the combination of these 3 types of updates that caused a system Signature somewhere to change? Doesn't Microsoft anticipate their own updates working with Bitlocker??

Comment: User1686, I have heard you say I could rollback the UEFI to previous version, if it contains the Storage Root Key in the TPM, and not a fTPM. How do I find out which one I have? Also, how do I backup the motherboard settings prior to making any further changes? Thank you sir.

Comment: @cuddlybear By definition every firmware update should make the TPM go into a new state that was saved before and thus lead to a recovery required for booting. Usually this is bypassed by the firmware updater by temporary disabling Bitlocker for the first boot after the firmware has been updated. Then the Bitlocker is able to update the TPM state and Bitlocker is fully functional again.

Comment: By what definition?

Comment: @user1686 The TPM measures the system state. If you update firmware the system state is expected to be different as the firmware is different.

Comment: I read that fTPM only is for AMD, but this is intel, and in UEFI, it says it has TTP. Separately, I just read an article that is very similar to this issue:

https://www.theregister.com/2022/08/15/bitlocker_microsoft/

On the Bitlocker recovery screen, to my surprise it actually says what caused this issue: “You need to enter your recovery key because Secure Boot policy has unexpectedly changed."

Comment: If I manually reinstall the same UEFI version with a USB, will that clear the TPM key or the Intel TTP key?

Comment: I meant to say Intel "PTT".